# Specific filter and calculation method mapping scenario - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Suppose I have a field called `isbn` on `stock_move`, this field is of `Boolean` type, I can create a method, with domain filter, which will bring all the `stock_move` objects, with `('isbn', '=', 'True'),`, and reflect that calculation on another field, like this:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('stock_move')
def _compute_amount_total(self):
    draft_orders = self.env['stock.move'].search([('isbn', '=', True)])
    product_uom_qty = sum(draft_orders.mapped('product_uom_qty'))
    for record in self:
        record.total_isbn = product_uom_qty
```

So, by far, this is a nice approach, but now, suppose I want to do this, but not for ALL the `stock_moves` in which the `isbn` field is checked, but just for the `stock_moves` I'm calling from let's say 4 `Many2one` fields in a model, ie:

```
stock_move1 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 1")
stock_move2 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 2")
stock_move3 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 3")
stock_move4 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 4")
```

I can call the `isbn` field on my model like this though:

```
stock_move1 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 1")
isbn1 = fields.Boolean(string="ISBN 1", related="stock_move1.isbn")
stock_move2 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 2")
isbn2 = fields.Boolean(string="ISBN 2", related="stock_move2.isbn")
stock_move3 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 3")
isbn3 = fields.Boolean(string="ISBN 3", related="stock_move3.isbn")
stock_move4 = fields.Many2one('stock.move', string="My Stock Move 4")
isbn4 = fields.Boolean(string="ISBN 4", related="stock_move4.isbn")
```

This should bring them, but actually I don't want to show them or anything on my view, just read those 4 `stock_moves` look for `isbn = True` and sum `product_uom_qty` on them.

I hope I've explained myself.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Can you explain what do you need exactly in a short sentence

Comment: Hi, I need to sum up all the product_uom_qty fields in the stock_moves I bring by these many2one fields in my form/view, and store the result in a field, if there is one, show that result, if I choose all the 4, the sum up all the four product_uom_qty in those four stock_moves.

Comment: So user select select a stock.move and you compute the total of quantity

Comment: Exactly, if 1, compute that one, if 2, or 4 compute all 4...

Comment: So why all this related fields just add a compute field that sum the selcted quantity

Comment: Because that is a constraint, I mean, the user will select a record, which has a one2many to stock_move, so it's a stock_move 'embedded' in those records, and that stock_move will have that Boolean field as an indicator that it was created from that specific view/circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends(
    'stock_move1.isbn', 'stock_move1.product_uom_qty',
    'stock_move2.isbn', 'stock_move2.product_uom_qty',
    'stock_move3.isbn', 'stock_move3.product_uom_qty',
    'stock_move4.isbn', 'stock_move4.product_uom_qty')
def _compute_amount_total(self):
    for record in self:
        moves = (record.stock_move1 +
            record.stock_move2 +
            record.stock_move3 +
            record.stock_move4).filtered('isbn')
        record.total_isbn = sum(moves.mapped('product_uom_qty'))
```

From what I understood from your description you don't really the `isbn1..4` related fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think @naglis jonailis has answered your question. You may get some errors because he didn't check the values are empty or not he concatenated the field directly.

```
                total_quantity = 0
                # check if the field is selected and add the quantity 
                if rec.many2one_field :
                      total_quantity =+ rec.many2one_field.product_uom_qty


                # affect the sum to your computed field
                 rec.compute_sum_field = total_quantity
```

And one thind why using four many2one use many2many user can select  many stock moved .

Comment: Mmmmmmm disn't understand your last comment

Comment: I need to "control" how many can be selected though :/, but maybe isn't the best solution, gonna try in a moment, Thank You

Comment: So you have a view that have four many2one when user select the total is computed again. Is this what you want

Comment: You can create a constrain to check the length of your many2many and this why you can simplify the code to use mapped and filtered methods

Comment: Thank You very much, I'll probably improve it anyways, it's just to ship it out soon, then make the adjustments needed :)